# Unable to install Graphene-SGX on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, security, ubuntu-18.04, intel, sgx

I am not able to install Graphene properly (https://graphene.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building.html). While running the sample code, I am getting the following error

`Cannot open device /dev/gsgx. Please make sure the Graphene SGX kernel module is loaded`.

This is probably because, during the installation command 
`sudo insmod gsgx.ko`, I got the following error

`insmod: ERROR: could not insert module gsgx.ko: Required key not available`.

Rest all (related to SGX) seems fine as I was able to run sample SGX examples and `sudo service aesmd status` gives

```html
aesmd.service - Intel(R) Architectural Enclave Service Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/aesmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-05-22 16:28:55 EDT; 2h 45min ago
  Process: 4404 ExecStart=/opt/intel/sgx-aesm-service/aesm/aesm_service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4403 ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 0750 /var/opt/aesmd/ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4402 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R aesmd:aesmd /var/opt/aesmd/ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4400 ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/aesmd/ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4391 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R aesmd:aesmd /var/run/aesmd/ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4388 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/aesmd/ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4369 ExecStartPre=/opt/intel/sgx-aesm-service/aesm/linksgx.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4405 (aesm_service)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/aesmd.service
           └─4405 /opt/intel/sgx-aesm-service/aesm/aesm_service
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the /dev/gsgx separately (as written in the [2b](https://graphene.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building.html#b-install-the-graphene-fsgsbase-driver-not-for-production) step)? I had the same error when trying to run some GSC examples, but following the 2b should work, even though it's not for production.